# With pytest and factory-boy, how do I create a factory for a non-traditional type of object?

Tags: django, python-3.x, model, pytest, factory-boy

I'm using Django 2, Python 3.7 and factory-boy.  Trying to create a factory for the django-address' AddressField -- https://pypi.org/project/django-address/ , which I guess is a non-traditional model, in that it doesn't inherit from `models.Model`.  I created this factory, using `objects = models.Manager()` ...

```py
class AddressFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Address Factory
    """
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        model = AddressField

    street_number = "123"
    route = "Rd"
    raw = "123 Fake Rd"
    formatted = "123 Fake Rd."
    latitude = 87.1234
    longitude = -100.12342
    locality = factory.SubFactory(LocalityFactory)

class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    name = "test model"
    address = factory.SubFactory(AddressFactory)
    enabled = True
    phone = "312-999-1234"
    email = "test@hello.com"
    web_site = "http://www.hello.com"

    @factory.post_generation
    def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for type in extracted:
                self.types.add(type)
        else:
            type = factory.SubFactory(CoopTypeFactory)
            self.types.all().set( (type) )
```

Then I have this test ...

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_address_create(self):
    """ Test address model """    # create customer model instance
    address = AddressFactory()
    assert address is not None
```

but running the test results in the below error ...

```
davea$ python manage.py test --settings=maps.test_settings
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
setUpTestData: Run once to set up non-modified data for all class methods.
setUp: Run once for every test method to setup clean data.
EsetUp: Run once for every test method to setup clean data.
.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_address_create (tests.test_models.ModelTests)
Test address model
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 126, in _get_manager
    manager = model_class.objects
AttributeError: type object 'AddressField' has no attribute 'objects'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_models.py", line 27, in test_address_create
    address = AddressFactory()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 46, in __call__
    return cls.create(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 141, in _generate
    return super(DjangoModelFactory, cls)._generate(strategy, params)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 279, in build
    kwargs=kwargs,
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 315, in instantiate
    return self.factory._create(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 184, in _create
    manager = cls._get_manager(model_class)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 130, in _get_manager
    manager = model_class._default_manager
AttributeError: type object 'AddressField' has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

What do I need to do to build a factory for this type of object?

**Edit:** This is my Coop model in all its glory ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

Comment: `AddressField` is just a `ForeignKey` to `address.models.Address`, so instead of use `AddressField` as a model in the `Meta class` you have use `address.models.Address`

Comment: @Motakjuq, in my models.py file, I have "address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)", so would I need to change that to "address = Address(on_delete=models.CASCADE)" as well and regenerate my migrations?

Comment: there is no need to change anything in `models.py`, just change the model attribute from the meta class in `AddressFactory`

Comment: I want my factories to be reflections of the models.  So my CoopFactory would link to the AddressFactory because Coop has a relationship with Address (or more specifically, AddressField).  So wouldn't changing the meta to a different object no longer accurately test how my models are set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base `Coop` model should be similar to:

```py
from address.models import AddressField
from django.db import models


class Coop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = AddressField()
```

To configure the factories in your tests, you have to create a factory for each model from `django-address`

```py
class CountryFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'address.Country'

    name = 'Test Country'
    code = '123'


class StateFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'address.State'

    name = 'Test State'
    code = '456'
    country = factory.SubFactory(CountryFactory)


class LocalityFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'address.Locality'

    name = 'Test Locality'
    postal_code = '123'
    state = factory.SubFactory(StateFactory)


class AddressFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'address.Address'

    street_number = "123"
    route = "Rd"
    raw = "123 Fake Rd"
    formatted = "123 Fake Rd."
    latitude = 87.1234
    longitude = -100.12342
    locality = factory.SubFactory(LocalityFactory)

class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    name = 'new Coop'
    address = factory.SubFactory(AddressFactory)
```

And the test will be:

```py
class FactoryTest(TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        coop_from_factory = CoopFactory()
        self.assertIsNotNone(coop_from_factory)

        coop = Coop.objects.create(name='test', address=coop_from_factory.address)
        self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Per my other comment, since my Coop model depends on AddressField (entire model listed as an edit), but my CoopFactory now depends on Address, aren't I testing a situation that doesn't reflect the reality of my application?

Comment: your `Coop` model has always depended of `address.model.Address`, because `AddressField` is a subclass of `models.ForeignKey` with some changes (https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address/blob/c5df849e73ff9eac93764cde6dff9adbdbb9de96/address/models.py#L299-L305), for that reason `address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)` is the same that `address = models.ForeingKey('address.Address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` at model level.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense.  So I'm getting an error when I run the test you suggested -- don't think it's related to you, but not sure.  The Coop factory is having trouble with creating a many-ot-many field, this line (added to quesiton) -- "self.types.all().set( (type) )".  I opened a seaprate SO question in case it's unrelated to this question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922901/in-factoryboy-how-do-i-set-a-many-to-many-field-in-my-factory

Comment: @Dave that problem is not related, but I commented a solution to that question