# In FactoryBoy, how do I set a many-to-many field in my factory?

Tags: django, unit-testing, many-to-many, factory-boy, factories

I'm using Django 2.2 and FactoryBoy to attempt to create some factories to produce the following models ...

```
class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()

    class Meta:
        # Creates a new unique constraint with the `name` field
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name'], name='coop_type_unq')]


class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    address = AddressField(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

Here is my factory for creating the Coop object ...

```
class CoopFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """
        Define Coop Factory
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Coop

    name = "test model"
    address = factory.SubFactory(AddressFactory)
    enabled = True
    phone = "312-999-1234"
    email = "test@hello.com"
    web_site = "http://www.hello.com"

    @factory.post_generation
    def types(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of types were passed in, use them
            for type in extracted:
                self.types.add(type)
        else:
            type = CoopTypeFactory()
            self.types.set( (type) )
```

This is my test ...

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create(self):
    """ Test customer model """    # create customer model instance
    coop_from_factory = CoopFactory()
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop_from_factory)

    coop = Coop.objects.create(name='test', address=coop_from_factory.address)
    self.assertIsNotNone(coop)
```

However, it doesn't seem to like this line

```
self.types.set( (type) )
```

from the factory, because the test dies with the below error.  What is the proper way to get my factory to work with a many-to-many field?

```
    ======================================================================
ERROR: test_coop_create (tests.test_models.ModelTests)
Test customer model
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_models.py", line 34, in test_coop_create
    coop_from_factory = CoopFactory()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 46, in __call__
    return cls.create(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 141, in _generate
    return super(DjangoModelFactory, cls)._generate(strategy, params)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 299, in build
    context=postgen_context,
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/declarations.py", line 623, in call
    instance, create, context.value, **context.extra)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/factories.py", line 96, in types
    self.types.set( (type) )
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1002, in set
    objs = tuple(objs)
TypeError: 'CoopType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: If you want to add an element to a M2M relation you have to do `self.types.add(type)`, the `set` method is used by the object manager (not a queryset) and received an iterable, so to fix the problem you have to change the `set` as `self.types.set([type])` or if you want to use a tuple `self.types.set( (type,) )`

Comment: I tried "self.types.add(type)" but this results in the error, "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SubFactory'".  When I tried, "self.types.set([type])", I get the same error "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SubFactory'".

Comment: I didn't see the previous line, replace `type = factory.SubFactory(CoopTypeFactory)` with `type = CoopTypeFactory()`, because you need to add a `CoopType` instance to the `types` relation

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with the complete details, but using "type = CoopTypeFactory()" and then "self.types.set( (type) )" results in the error "TypeError: 'CoopType' object is not iterable".  I "think" I have implemented it per your suggestion.

Comment: The value `(type)` is not a tuple because a comma is missing, you have to change the `set` as `self.types.set( (type, ) )`, be aware of the `,` after `type`